# Add a new column to an existing MySeQL table and without overlapping exsisting table values

Tags: android

i have create one Database and add some columns in that DB.now i need some columns added in the existing db with a new columns but without overlapping the exsisting table values.

i have face some error for adding new tables with exsisting table values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use standard SQL in a two-step process to insert new rows and update existing rows. The following is one way to do it, but it’s not the best way:

insert into t1 (a, b, c)
select l.d, l.e, l.f
from t2 as l
    left outer join t1 as r on l.d = r.a
where r.a is null;
update t1 as l
    inner join t2 as r on l.a = r.d
    set l.b = r.e, l.c = r.f;

Answer (score 1):

You can use ALTER TABLE in your onUpgrade() method

```
 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  //add new coloumn and change your database version to an increased new value
 if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN NEW_COLOUMN_NAME TEXT NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following query

INSERT INTO new_table(col1, col2, col3....) SELECT col1, col2, col3.... FROM existing_table